# Saving JSON data to DB in Zotonic

Tags: json, postgresql, erlang, zotonic

Im trying to write a small app that retrieves a JSON file (it contains a list of items, which all have some properties), saves its contents to the DB and then displays some of it later on. I have Zotonic up and running, and generating some HTML is no problem.
ATM i'm stuck trying to figure out how to define a custom resource and how to get the data from the JSON in the DB. When the data is there I should be fine, that part seems covered ok by the documentation.
I wrote some standalone erlang scripts that fetch the data and I noticed that Zotonic has a library for decoding JSON so that part should be fine. Any tips on where to put which code or where to look further?

Comment: Why not ask in Zotonic group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zotonic-users?

Comment: Good suggestion, posted a question there as well (in the dev group though). For now i'm going over the source and some example sites/modules on github which is helpful but progress is slow (rewarding nonetheless :)   ). Seems that using the z_db functions are the way to go for the DB interactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z_db module allows for creating custom tables by using:

```
z_db:create_table(Table, Cols, Context).
```

The Table variable is your table name which can be either an atom or a list containing a single atom.
The Cols is a list of column definitions, which are defined by records. Currently the record definition (you can find this in include/zotonic.hrl) is:

```
-record(column_def, {name, type, length, is_nullable=true, default, primary_key}).
```

See [Erlang docs on records](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html) for more info on records

Example code which I put in users/sites/[sitename]/models/m_[sitename].erl:

```
init(Context) ->
        case z_db:table_exists(?table,Context) of
        false ->
                z_db:create_table(tablename,
                [
                #column_def{name=id, type="serial"},
                #column_def{name=gid, type="integer", is_nullable=false},
                #column_def{name=magnitude, type="real"},
                #column_def{name=depth, type="real"},
                #column_def{name=location, type="character varying"},
                #column_def{name=time, type="integer"},
                #column_def{name=date, type="integer"}
                ], Context);
        true -> ok
        end,
        ok.
```

Pay attention to what options of the record you specify. Most of the errors I got were e.g. from specifying a length on the integer fields.

The `models/m_sitename:init/1` does not get called on site start. The `sitename:init/1` does get called so I call the init function there to ensure the table exists. Example:

```
init(Context) ->
        m_sitename:init(Context).
```

It is called by Zotonic with the Context variable of the site automatically. You can get this variable manually as well with `z:c(sitename).`. So if you call the `m_sitename:init(Context).` from somewhere else you would do:

```
m_sitename:init(z:c(sitename)).
```

Next, insertion in the DB can be done with:

```
z_db:insert(Table, PropList, Context).
```

Where Table is again an atom or a list containing a single atom representing the table name. Context is the same as above.
PropList is a property list which is a list containing tuples consisting of two elements where the first is an atom and the second is its associated value/property. Example:

```
PropList = [
            {row, Value},
            {anotherrow, AnotherValue}
           ].

Table = tablename.
Context = z:c(sitename).
z_db:insert(Table, PropList, Context).
```

See [Erlang docs on Property Lists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) for more info on property lists.

=== The dependencies have been updated so if you build from source the step directly below is no longer needed ===

The JSON part is bit more tricky. Included with Zotonic are mochijson2 and as a secondary dependency also [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy). The latest version of jiffy contains jiffy:decode/2 which allows you to specify maps as a return type. Much more readable than the standard `{struct, {struct, <<"">>}}` monster. To update to the latest version edit the line in `deps/twerl/rebar.config` that says

```
{jiffy, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/davisp/jiffy.git", {tag, "0.8.3"}}},
```

to

```
{jiffy, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/davisp/jiffy.git", {tag, "0.14.3"}}},
```

Now run `z:m().` in the [Zotonic shell](http://zotonic.com/docs/0.13/manuals/cli-shell.html). (you must do this after every change in your code).
Now check in the Zotonic shell if there is a jiffy:decode/2 available by typing `jiffy: <tab>`, it will show a list of available functions and their arity.

To retrieve a JSON file from the internet run:

```
{ok, {{_, 200, _}, _, Body}} = httpc:request(get, {"url-to-JSON-here", []}, [], [])
```

Which will yield the variable Body with the contents. See [Erlang docs on http client](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html) for more info on this call.

Next convert the contents of Body to Erlang terms with:

```
JsonData = jiffy:decode(Body, [return_maps]).
```

What you have to do next depends a lot on the structure of your JSON resource. Keep in mind that everything is now in binary UTF-8 encoded strings! If you print JsonData to screen (just enter `JsonData.` in your Zotonic/Erlang shell) you will see a lot of `#map{<<"key"", <<"Value">>}` this.
My data was nested so I had to extract the needed data like this:

```
[{_,ItemList}|_] = ListData.
```

This gave me a list of maps, and in order to deal with them as individual items I used the following function:

```
 get_maps([]) ->
     done; 
 get_maps([First|Rest]) ->
     Map = maps:get(<<"properties">>, First),
     case is_map(Map) of
             true ->
                     map_to_proplist(Map),
                     get_maps(Rest);
             false -> done
             end,
     done; 
get_maps(_) ->
     done.
```

As you might remember, the `z_db:insert/3` function needs a property list to populate rows, so that what the call to `map_to_proplist/1` is for. How this function looks is completely dependent on how your data looks but as an example here is what worked for me:

```
map_to_proplist(Map) ->
        case is_map(Map) of
                true ->
                        {Value1,_}         = string:to_integer(binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key1">>, Map))),
                        {Value2,_}   = string:to_float(binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key2">>, Map))),
                        {Value3,_}       = string:to_float(binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key3">>, Map))),
                        Value4        = binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key4">>, Map)),
                        {Value5,_}        = string:to_integer(binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key5">>, Map))),
                        {Value6,_}        = string:to_integer(binary_to_list(maps:get(<<"key6">>, Map))),
                        PropList = [{rowname1, Value1}, {rowname2, Value2}, {rowname3, Value3}, {rowname4, Value4}, {rowname5, Value5}, {rowname6, Value6}],
                        m_sitename:insert_items(PropList,z:c(sitename)),
                        ok;
                false ->
                        ok
                end.
```

See the [documentation on string:to_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#to_integer-1) as to why the tuples are needed when casting. The call to `m_sitename:insert_items(PropList,z:c(sitename))` calls the z_db:insert/3 in `models/m_sitename.erl` but wrapped in a catch:

```
insert_items(PropList,Context) ->
        (catch z_db:insert(?table, PropList, Context)).
```

Ok, quite a long post but this should get you up and running if you were looking for this answer.

The above was done with Zotonic 0.13.2 on Erlang/OTP 18.
A repost (except the JSON part) of my post [in the Zotonic Developers group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zotonic-developers/LgrmicA_8c8).